# Rails, seeding code is difficult to write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I'm new to working with db's.  We have a rails app being used in production on the server.  We continue to do development locally.  Some of that development results in adding stuff to the db.  In order to keep the dbs in sync, we are manually writing seed code for everything we do locally, then we plan on uploading the seed code and running the rake command on the server.  Is this the way this type of thing is typically done?  Is there an easy way to write this seed code?  It seems to be laborious and painful, I'm just browsing the db to try and figure out what the latest changes are, and then writing code that will hopefully add the same data to the db on the server.   thanks

Comment: Is this something you could do with migrations (also adding to `db/seeds.rb` for any fresh installations you might need to make, like a new developer coming onto the project)?

Comment: I don't know.  Again, I'm very new to this. My understanding is that migrations are for adding schema, and seeding is for adding data.  This definitely involves adding data. Maybe there are generators for seeding, like there are for migrations. Or maybe my understanding of what they are, is inaccurate.

Comment: Seeding is done via a single file - `db/seeds.rb`. If you're needing to add new data over time, your best bet is using migrations, because seeding is intended to be run only one time. You *do* typically use migrations for schema changes, but from your description, it seems like they would also be your best there, as well.

Comment: Any answer would depend a lot on the case. For example: Is your app like a contact db and you get new vcard files a lot or is it rather like a service that pulls together a growing number of apis in order to provide a common interface? Does the data change on the server through users, services, cronjobs, mails, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue in the past, and we did it with migrations.  Do something like

```
class AddSomeStuffToMyThing < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    widget=MyThing.new()
    widget.attr_1 = "some stuff"
    widget.attr_2 = 341
    ...
  def self.down
    widget = MyThing.find_by_attr_1("some stuff")
    widget.destroy
```

If you are frequently changing the seed data in your database, then perhaps you should start looking into a schemaless solution like Mongo or CouchDB